# CS1061- does not contain a definition for 'SendKeys' and no accessible extension method 'SendKeys'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a generic code for "ElementIsVisible" so that the generic code can be used in multiple places. I keep getting this error. How do I correct this?

```
Error   CS1061  'Shared' does not contain a definition for 'SendKeys' and no accessible extension method 'SendKeys' accepting a first argument of type 'Shared' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

**Here is my code**

```
 public Shared WaitUntilElementIsVisible(By by)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance.webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
            return this;
        }
```

```
public Page Physician(string physician)
        {
            
            var WeekStarted = PrShared.Page.WaitUntilElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@id='fyd_weekStarted']"));
            WeekStarted.SendKeys(weekStarted);
            return this;
        }
```

```
**TO TEST**
Test.Page.Physician(Data.WeekStarted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `WaitUntilElementIsVisible()` you have `return this` but you haven't defined what `this` is. The `wait` in `WaitUntilElementIsVisible()` returns an `IWebElement`... just return that but you have to change your return type to `IWebElement`.

```
public IWebElement WaitUntilElementIsVisible(By by)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance.webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    return wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
}
```

---

An additional suggestion would be to add a parameter to this method for timeout so that you can adjust the wait time, e.g.

```
public IWebElement WaitUntilElementIsVisible(By by, int timeout)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance.webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
    return wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown how `Shared` is defined so I had to change the return type here. If you want to return `Shared`, you'll have to update your question and show the code where you define the `Shared` type.